# Empty css generated by Guard

Tags: css, sass, guard

I'm entirely new with Guard.

For unknown reasons, Guard is generating empty css, after changes of sass files.

I'm using ruby 2.2.1p85 and I'm on a Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).

What could I do to solve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to open an issue.

Often, it's good to at least run Guard in debugging mode with `bundle exec guard -d` and paste the output. It can also help to show your `Guardfile` and `Gemfile`.